# Are real polynomial maps regular in the sense of Gabrielov?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, analytic-functions

Let $\varphi: X\to Y$ an real analytic map of real analytic manifolds
and $x\in X$. Let us write $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ for the algebra of germs at $x$ of real analytic functions on $X$ and $ \widehat{\mathcal O}_{X,x}$ for the the algebra of formal power series at $x$. Similarly we use $\mathcal O_{Y,\varphi(x)}$ and  $ \widehat{\mathcal O}_{Y,\varphi(x)}$ for the corresponding algebras at $\varphi(x)\in Y$. The map $\varphi$ induces algebra morphisms $\varphi_x^*: \mathcal O_{Y,\varphi(x)}\to \mathcal O_{X,x}$ and its Taylor expansion  $\widehat{\varphi}_x^*: \widehat{\mathcal O}_{Y,\varphi(x)}\to \widehat{\mathcal O}_{X,x}$.

A. Gabrielov uses the following three notions of rank of $\varphi$ at $x$:
\begin{align}
&r_1(x)=\mbox{rank of the Jacobian of $\varphi$ at a generic point nearby $x$},\\
&r_2(x)=\dim(\widehat{\mathcal O}_{Y,\varphi(x)}/\ker \widehat{\varphi}_x^*),\\
&r_3(x)=\dim(\mathcal O_{Y,\varphi(x)}/\ker \varphi_x^*).
\end{align}
One observes $r_1(x)\le r_2(x)\le r_3(x)$. The map $\varphi$ is said to be regular in the sense of Gabrielov at $x$ if $r_1(x)=r_3(x)$, i.e., the three ranks coincide. It is said to be regular in the sense of Gabrielov if it has this property at all $x\in X$.

I wonder if a polynomial map $\varphi:X=\mathbb R^n\to Y=\mathbb R^m$ is Gabrielov regular? Maybe somebody has suggestions how to argue or where to read about it.